# How to Call A Method after certain time has passed in C#

Tags: c#, methods, stopwatch

I'm trying to call an method in this if statement after a certain time (15 seconds) has ended, but it doesn't seem to work at all not print out the text in the method. How would I go about doing this, I have tried researching on how the stopwatch works but it doesn't seem to be working. Thank your for your help.

*I have tried this code*

```
    Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    if (watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds == 15)
    {
       Method();
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us why (you think) you need this and what is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: A stopwatch is what is is- it stops time. It is not executing code magically. your watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds is probably at 0.000001 or so - not 15. You might want to use Thread.Sleep() if you want to force your program to sleep a bit, else you need to look here: [Timer with callback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149618(v=vs.110).aspx). It has some example at the bottom.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`Task` is what you need

```
Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15)).ContinueWith(o => { Method(); });
```

More about Asynchronous programming [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. The most elegant solution there.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is to halt your execution for a short while, and then invoke the method.
The most trivial way to do so is:

```
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
Method();
```

But note that your thread is not doing anything during this time, so a better way would be to use the TPL, and **async** methods, but for your needs the code above will probably do :)